# Angular2 forcing reload ngIf (or alternative in this case)

Tags: angular

This a bootstrap twitter, `button` this control to data toggle collapse

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ....
               aria-expanded="false">
```

this a bootstrap twitter inside of `nav-tabs`, this show on button click

```html
<div *ngIf="ifActivoControl('1' + contadorObjet.name)"

      class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item"
        src="//www.youtube.com/v/YX.....">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

When angular2 render for the first time this function `ifActivoControl('1' + contadorObjet.name)` return false.

*This function is to test the not taken seriously*

```
ifActivoControl(test: any): boolean{

      let booleanStr = document.getElementById(test).getAttribute('aria-expanded');
      let bool: boolean = false;

      if(booleanStr === 'false'){
        bool = false;
      }else{
        bool = true;
      }

    return bool;
    }
```

Return false because `aria-expanded="false"` but when this switch to true `aria-expanded="true"`, how can I do, `ngIf` to check again.

This may not be the best way to do, but it is, as I have tried I hope you understand what I mean.

---

**UPDATE:**

I solved after reading this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827334/triggering-angular2-change-detection-manually/34829089#34829089) by Marcos Rajcok and reading this,

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html#!#detach

but I do not know if this is the best way. The first tests I do, it works as expected

Comment: I think you need to run change detection manually..

Comment: @PankajParkar thanks for your time you think this answer can help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827334/triggering-angular2-change-detection-manually/34829089#34829089 I am new to Angular2

Comment: Correct.. Chose one of the option from it.

Comment: can you provide a plnkr example?

Comment: @PankajParkar I solved thank you for your comment